# How to toggle editButtonItem with rxswift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have the following setup

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in

        print("edit tapped")

        if let isEditing = self?.tableView.isEditing {

            self?.tableView.setEditing(!isEditing, animated: true)

        }

        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

The problem is left bar button item is not toggled on tap. I.E text in the left bar button should change from **Edit** to  **Done**.

Changing button title in onNext method does not work either.

Comment: I would recommend not to subscribe to the tap event on the editButton, because it will remove it's default edit/done toggle behaviour. I believe I found a better alternative, by calling: rx.methodInvoked(#selector(UIViewController.setEditing(_:animated:))). Also if you're using a UITableViewController, calling seEditing on the controller instead of the TableView is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `setEditing` on `self`, not the table view. If `self` is a `UITableViewController`, this will also change the editing state of the table view.